# how to translate d3.js tree to a new position after searching a node

Tags: d3.js, three.js

```
here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/5dsnucue/29/
```

I am searching node/nodes on the basis of selected index changed, which is working(changing color of the search node to red).
    I want to translate the whole tree to the new position if I entered the full term name in textbox (not a single character like "good" not a or z or n).
    I want to translate the tree in such a way that my searched node show at the middle of the page.

Comment: The code should be in the content of the post

Comment: it's a very long code along with a json file. please if you can look at here https://jsfiddle.net/5dsnucue/33/